# Configuration.GetAPIContext() not found in .net PayPal sdk

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm working on integrating Paypal in .net 2012 MVC 4

Everything is good but when it comes to calls `"Configuration.GetAPIContext();"` it generates error as it is not found. I installed PayPal sdk for Rest APi using NUGET.

```
 var apiContext = Configuration.GetAPIContext();
```

Can anyone assist me to know what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create public class called Configuration (or any other name) for PayPal!

Look into `PayPal-NET-SDK-develop\Samples\Source\Utilities\Configuration.cs`.

That is what you want!

Comment: GitHub link: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/blob/develop/Samples/Source/Utilities/Configuration.cs